# Removing elements from the list based on the other list in the correct order

Tags: python, list

I want to do the following in Python:

Let's say we have two lists:

```
A = [3, 10, 100, 3, 100, 10, 5]
B = [3, 100, 10]
```

I want to delete B from A only if it's in the correct order.

So the output for this example would be:

```
A = [3, 10, 100, 5]
```

Note that 3, 10, 100 were not deleted from A, because they weren't in the same sequence as B.
The lists I'm working on will never have two same numbers next to each other. What is important is the position of a number in the list.
More examples, to hopefully make it more clear:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
B = [3, 2, 1]
```

The expected output would be:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This way the sequence of A is preserved.

Comment: Do they need to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, they need to be consecutive.

Comment: What about `A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; B = [1, 1]`; do you want to remove several occurrences?

Comment: I don't care about it, since my lists will never have repeating numbers next to each other. So it can work however in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a substring search question, so KMP, BM, etc sub-string search algorithms could be applied here.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/m00nlight/daa6786cc503fde12a77) is a KMP algorithm implemented by Python from GitHub Gist.

Use it to calculate the matched position, and finally remove the match:

```
A = [3, 10, 100, 3, 100, 10, 5]
B = [3, 100, 10]
result = KMP().search(A, B)
print(result)
#assuming at least one match is found
print(A[:result[0]:] + A[result[0]+len(B):])
```

Output:

```
[3]
[3, 10, 10, 5]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you are allowed to copy this code here. From GitHub's Tos: "If you set your pages and repositories to be viewed publicly, you grant each User of GitHub a nonexclusive, worldwide license to use, display, and perform Your Content through the GitHub Service and to reproduce Your Content **solely on GitHub** as permitted through GitHub's functionality (for example, through forking). You may grant further rights if you adopt a license." (Emphasis mine). I didn't find any indication that the author adopted any licence.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I wasn't aware of that, I added a link to the Github gist instead.